# Delaying page transitioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transition

Since smoothState.js never ever worked for me for some reason im trying something my own, just simpler.

Question: How do i delay the default page transition so it starts after my css animation ended, pref. not preloading the other page as it will start with a fadeIn animation. Im this far.

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  $(body).addClass("lightSpeedOut")(function(){
    window.location = href;
  });
});
});
```

And the html is here

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3 no-padding">
            <img src="img/t-cover.jpg" class="img-responsive-cover" alt="girl in a white top" />
            <div class="overlay">
                <h2>Tops & T-Shirts</h2>
                <p><a href="html/tops.html"> Enter the world of Isabel Marant, Alice and Olivia and more...</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait for the animation event to end then redirect the user.

```js
var ANIMATION_END = 'animationend webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd';

$( 'body' ).addClass( 'lightSpeedOut' ).one( ANIMATION_END, function () {
    window.location = href;
} );
```

Comment: seems easier than what i see on the net elsewhere, but i got a different problem. if i add yours (or even my own code i posted above) nothing happens at all if i click on the link. if i remove the last function part it does the default transition. cant seem to see where its going wrong though.

https://plnkr.co/edit/PowFwgszTk9Z2ZdR70Gd?p=preview

Comment: I may have misunderstood but my interpretation of your question and what you were trying to achieve was: _I'm running an animation and want to redirect after that animation has completed._

Comment: yes, but as you see in the fiddle that nothing happens after i click on the link. no redirect no animation.

Comment: You need to include `jQuery`. Also, I don't think tools like Plunker and JSFiddle will actually redirect.

Comment: they did if i remove most of it. but even on my computer it doesnt redirect. the code you see on plunker is the one i tried ( how i input ur suggestion ) and it still isnt working. jquery and all integrated.

Comment: `jQuery` is not being included in your `Plunker`. Checking the console shows an error of `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` which is saying that `jQuery` is not define as `$` is an alias for `jQuery`. Please review my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/29thpr3m/). It won't redirect as I don't think that's allowed so I replaced the `window.location` with an `alert()` message that will run after the animation has completed. I also noticed you have `$( body )` instead of `$( 'body' )` with quotation marks which will also cause an issue.

Comment: Oh yes, ok i will try it in a bit at work if it works i will mark ur answer. Thanks already for ur help

Comment: you're a genius! i hope this helps others cuz whenever i googled stuff it made it all so complicated while this is insanely easy. Thanks mate!!